# Send and Receive Email in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0, smtp

I am creating Contact Us web page in ASP.NET where user can enter all his details. After entering details when he click on submit buttons I; as a admin should receive all his details he enter into contact us page and he; as a user should receive thanks or confirmation message. I tried to search and follow number of blog but all those blog explain how to send email.

I am able to send email to user once he/she click on submit button but I; as an admin not able to receive user info he entered into Web Page.

Can someone provide me sample code or guide me how should I achieve this task in ASP.NET and C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean send 2 separate emails, [cc and/or bcc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx) (which could then be the answer as well)?

Comment: Confused. So you can send one email, and not the other? Is your question about email at all? Or is it how to read the form fields that were posted to your Contact us page?

Comment: Suppose you are user and you fill out contact us form. I being admin will get all your information which you enter into form and you'll receive thank you message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it. This includes ajaxControlToolkit as well, but you do not need this. But I would recommend the required field validator.  I have 3 textboxes. One is for their name, 2nd is for their email, and the 3rd is the description of what they want or need.

**HTML**

```
<article>
        <p>        
            <asp:Label ID="lblYourName" runat="server" Text="Your Name: ">
            </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="tbEmployeeName" runat="server" Width="151px" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmployeeName" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Email is Required!" ControlToValidate="tbEmployeeName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="tbEmployeeName"
                FilterType="Custom, UppercaseLetters, LowercaseLetters"
                ValidChars=" "/>
        </p>

        <p>        
            <asp:Label ID="lblYourEmailAddress" runat="server" Text="Your E-mail: ">
            </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="tbEmployeeEmail" runat="server" Width="150px" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmployeeEmail" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="You're Email Address is Required!" ControlToValidate="tbEmployeeEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="tbEmployeeEmail"
                FilterType="Custom, UppercaseLetters, LowercaseLetters, Numbers"
                ValidChars=".@"/>
        </p>

        <p>
            Explain why you would like to have an account.
        </p>
        <p>        
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbEmployeeRequest" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="250px" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmployeeRequest" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Message is required!" ControlToValidate="tbEmployeeRequest"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender2" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="tbEmployeeRequest"
                FilterType="Custom, UppercaseLetters, LowercaseLetters, Numbers"
                ValidChars=". ;!?'" />
        </p>
        <p>        
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Font-Size="Small" Height="33px" Width="72px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CausesValidation="true"/>
```

**Behind Code**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Page.IsValid)
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("toEmail@Email.com"));
                msg.From = new MailAddress(tbEmployeeEmail.Text);
                msg.Subject = tbEmployeeName.Text + " requests an account!";
                msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                msg.Body = tbEmployeeRequest.Text;

                //CONFIGURE SMTP OBJECT
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.yoursmtpclient.com");

                //SEND EMAIL
                smtp.Send(msg);

                tbEmployeeEmail.Text = null;
                tbEmployeeName.Text = null;
                tbEmployeeRequest.Text = null;

                lblMessage.Text = "Your request has been sent. Please wait 2-3 days for a response.";
            }
        }
```

As you can tell, I use a label to tell them that their response will take a few days. What you can then use instead of the label like I do, is use a jQuery Modal popup that says thank you and any other information you need. If you do not know how to use jQuery, this is a good way to start. http://jqueryui.com/demos/ . If you wanted to send an email message back that says whatever you want it to say, you can manipulate the code above to do so. Instead of having the msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("toEmail@email.com") you could put msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(tbEmployeeEmail.Text); and send the email to them. I think (as an end user) this would be annoying though to check my email to see if I get a reponse, I'd rather know straight from the page. I hope this helps!